# Get the substring before the middle occurrence of a separator in java

Tags: java, regex, string, text

I have a string `bac/xaz/wed/rgc`. I want to get the substring before and after the middle / in the string.

I don't find the solution with string split. how to achieve this? I am not sure if I have to use regex and split the string.

Comment: It depends on how you approaches this problem.
Lets say you have 5 '/'s, you want to split at the third one; for 7 '/'s, you want to split at the fifth one. Or you would like to split at the second one in all cases.

Comment: Hi @Alphaharrius, I always have odd number of '/'s and want to split exactly at the middle one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public static void main(String ...args) {
        String value = "bac/xaz/wed/rgc/wed/rgc";
        // Store all indexes in a list
        List<Integer> indexList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < value.length(); i++) {
            if (value.charAt(i) == '/') {
                indexList.add(i);
            }
        }
        // Get the middle index from the list, works for odd number only.
        int middleIndex = indexList.get(indexList.size() / 2);
        System.out.println("First half: " + value.substring(0, middleIndex));
        System.out.println("Second half: " + value.substring(middleIndex + 1));
    }
```

Not an elegant solution, but it can handle as much '/' you gave it, as long as the total number of '/' is odd number.
Using an `ArrayList` might be overkill, but it works XD.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split` function to achieve that, using `/` as a delimiter:

```
String str = "bac/xaz/wed/rgc";
String[] arr = str.split('/');
```

You'll get an array of 4 strings: `["bac", "xaz", "wed", "rgc"]`.

From then on, you can retrieve the one that you want. If I understand well, you are interested in the elements 1 and 2:

```
String before = arr[1];
String after = arr[2];
```

If you meant to get the whole sub-string before the middle `/`, you can still concatenate the first two strings:

```
String strbefore = arr[0] + arr[1];
```

Same goes for the rest:

```
String strafter = arr[2] + arr[3];
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a simple solution

```java
String str = "bac/xaz/wed/rgc";
int loc = str.indexOf("/",str.indexOf('/')+1);
String str1 = str.substring(0,loc);
String str2 = str.substring(loc+1,str.length());
System.out.println(str1);
System.out.println(str2);
```

```
bac/xaz
wed/rgc
```